# linked list for authentication

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following code, from which I am trying to store a username and password in a linked list & authenticate against a user's input from a scanner but can't seem to get it working whatsoever. Any hep would be appreciated.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.LinkedList;

 //Linked lists declared to store, auctions, users, and items
 public class System1{

private static LinkedList<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();
public static String username;
public static String password;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,       InterruptedException {

    //User.setuser();

    String username = "user";
    String password = "pw123";

    users.add(new User("user", "pw123"));
    users.add(new User("user1", "pw123"));
    users.add(new User("user2", "pw123"));


    User.validateLogIn(users, username, password);

    System.out.println("If true you are logged in:" + User.userLogedIn);
```

2nd class

```
public class User {

public User(String username, String password) {
}
static boolean userLogedIn;

public static void validateLogIn( LinkedList<User> users, String username,      String password) {

Iterator<User> spin = users.iterator();
while (spin.hasNext()){
    User user = spin.next();

    //System.out.println("Searching");
    //System.out.println(username);
    if(username.equals(user.setUsername()) && password.equals(user.setPassword())) {
        //System.out.println("BINGO!");
        userLogedIn=true;
    } else {
        //return false;
        //System.out.println("User not found" + "\n");
    }
    }
 }

private String setUsername() {
String username = "user1";
System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
username = scanner.nextLine();

return username;
}

private String setPassword() {
String password = "pw123";
return password ;
}

/*public static void setuser(){
 System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System1.username = scanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Your username is " + System1.username);
 System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
 Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
 System1.password = scanner1.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Your password is " + System1.password);
 }*/
```

Comment: `if(username.equals(user.setUsername()) && password.equals(user.setPassword()))` have a think about what this line is trying to do

Comment: Validation right?
if the username that is in the current iteration is equal to the username being set by the user, same with the password, then x will happen. Right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to store the user name and the password you add to your linked list(in the User class builder)

Second, it's not clear what you're trying to do in your validation. you don't need to pass all those arguments, the LinkedList id more then enough.

something like this:
System1.java:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.LinkedList;

 //Linked lists declared to store, auctions, users, and items
 public class System1{

    private static LinkedList<User> users;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    users = new LinkedList<User>()
    users.add(new User("user", "pw123"));
    users.add(new User("user1", "pw123"));
    users.add(new User("user2", "pw123"));

    User.validateLogIn(users);

    System.out.println("If true you are logged in:" + User.userLogedIn);
}
```

User.java:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class User {

```
private String userName;
private String password;
public static boolean userLogedIn;

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.userName = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public static void validateLogIn( LinkedList<User> users) {

    userLogedIn = false;

    String usernameToCheck, passwordToCheck;
    System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    usernameToCheck = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
    passwordToCheck = scanner.nextLine();

    Iterator<User> spin = users.iterator();
    while (spin.hasNext()){
        User user = spin.next();

        //System.out.println("Searching");
        //System.out.println(username);
        String userToCheck
        if(user.userName.equals(userToCheck) && user.password.equals(passwordToCheck)) {
            //System.out.println("BINGO!");
            userLogedIn=true;
        } else {
            //return false;
            //System.out.println("User not found" + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help.
I am trying to get my validation to take the username and the password from the linked list where they're stored, and check if they're equal to the users put \(username and password) from the console.

Comment: This is exactly what this code does, it gets the username and the password from the console (through the scanner) and check it against every record in the LinkedList